# MacBook Air Facetime HD

Tags: release-loki, macbook, webcam

My Macbook Air runs Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki and my webcam is not working out of the box. First thing I've done was trying to identify the precise device

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lspci**

```
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera
```

What I can assume, first of all, is that the webcam is not recognised as an usb device but as a pci one.

Sincerely speaking, I don't know if this represent a problem or not.

However, as far as I can see, the unique solution online is [bcwc_pcie driver](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki). This driver was created for FacetimeHD (Broadcom 0x1570) PCIe webcam.

I've followed the [Get started](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started) wiki page, extracting the firmware and, then, installing it, but I really can't make the webcam working. To sum up what I did was:

- Going to my Documents folders

`cd Documents`

- `sudo apt-get install curl xz-utils cpio`
- `git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git`
- `cd bcwc_pcie/firmware/`
- `enter preformatted text here`
- `$ make`
- `# make install`

The result was:

```
luca@lucabook:~/Documents/bcwc_pcie/firmware$ make

Checking dependencies for driver download...
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/bin/xzcat
/bin/cpio

Downloading the driver, please wait...


Found matching hash from OS X, El Capitan 10.11.3
==> Extracting firmware...
 --> Decompressing the firmware using gzip...
 --> Deleting temporary files...
 --> Extracted firmware version 1.43.0

luca@lucabook:~/Documents/bcwc_pcie/firmware$ sudo su
root@lucabook:/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/firmware# make install
Copying firmware into '//lib/firmware/facetimehd'
root@lucabook:/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/firmware#
```

Now, after the firmware extraction, I installed it (following the Ubuntu/Debian instructions):

- `sudo apt-get install  linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-42-lowlatency git kmod libssl-dev checkinstall`
- removed the "old" bcwc_pcie driver directory

  `rm -rf bcwc-pcie/`
- git it again:

  `$ git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git`

Now make the kernel module:

```
luca@lucabook:~/Documents/bcwc_pcie$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic/build M=/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_ddr.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_hw.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_drv.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_ringbuf.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_isp.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_v4l2.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_buffer.o
  CC [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/fthd_debugfs.o
  LD [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/facetimehd.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/facetimehd.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/facetimehd.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic
```

And make install it:

```
luca@lucabook:~/Documents/bcwc_pcie$ sudo su
root@lucabook:/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie# make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic/build M=/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic'
INSTALL /home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie/facetimehd.ko
At main.c:158:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
DEPMOD  4.10.0-42-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic'
```

To end the installation, I only run depmod and loaded the kernel module:

```
root@lucabook:/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie# depmod
root@lucabook:/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie# modprobe facetimehd
```

Listing the active modules, this is what I can see:

```
root@lucabook:/home/luca/Documents/bcwc_pcie# lsmod | grep facetimehd
facetimehd            102400  0
videobuf2_dma_sg       16384  1 facetimehd
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 facetimehd
videobuf2_core         40960  2 facetimehd,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              172032  3 facetimehd,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
```

The question is, why my webcam is still not working?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, MacBook Air late 2014.
On Elementary Os Loki 4.1
Kernel: 4.9

after doing everything exactly the same as you, I ran:

```
sudo modprobe -r facetimehd
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

And now the camera works perfectly.

It's here in "additional notes": https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started#devvideo-not-created

Comment: Thank you guys!! i have installed ubuntu 18 in a 8gb usb and is running now on an Macbook air with facetime support by following your instructions with some minor adjustments due to version of headers.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately continue to get this after the 'make install' step.  Any ideas?

Tonys-MacBook-Air:/usr/src/facetimehd-0.1# sudo make install

make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/build M=/usr/src/facetimehd-0.1 modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
INSTALL /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/extra/facetimehd.ko
SIGN    /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/extra/facetimehd.ko
At main.c:160:

- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
  sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic
  Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
  root@Tonys-MacBook-Air:/usr/src/facetimehd-0.1# printf "done\n\n";
  done